# Design for Users or correct UX practices?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, user-centered-design

I was working with a product few days ago and interacted with various stakeholders who have seen the product and users closely. Unfotunately, I did not have access to the user base and was not able to conduct research study on user behaviour.

There were couple of feature sets that the stakeholders wanted the re imagined product to have. For example, using a particular UI elements (button/accordion/radios instead of dropdowns for more than 3 options) is used by the user extensively for long time.

Now the question is do we design for users or as per correct UX practices (consider example of using radio buttons for selection instead of dropdown when there is 5+ options to be selected.

What would be your strategy or the workable strategy in such cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to battle for UX over Marketing with regards to product navigation?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/133906/how-to-battle-for-ux-over-marketing-with-regards-to-product-navigation)

Comment: Correct UX practice IS to design for users. I really don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: @Peter you're right, but I think he means *UX theory on best practices* which no always aligns with what users want or are used to

Comment: @Devin thats right !